# difficulty to define the monad on all values

Tags: haskell

I trying to write monad that multiply all data nodes by given number.
I don't know how to define the Monad correctly.

```
module Main where  
data LinkedList a = NodeWithoutNext a | Node a (LinkedList a) deriving (Show)

instance Functor LinkedList where
  fmap f (NodeWithoutNext x) = NodeWithoutNext (f x)
  fmap f (Node a next) = Node (f a) (fmap f next)

instance Applicative LinkedList where
   pure = NodeWithoutNext
   (NodeWithoutNext f) <*> (NodeWithoutNext x) = NodeWithoutNext (f x)
   (NodeWithoutNext f) <*> (Node a next) = Node (f a) (fmap f next)

instance Monad LinkedList where
   return = NodeWithoutNext
   (NodeWithoutNext a) >>= f = f a
   **(Node a next) >>= f =  Node (f a) (next >>= f)**

main :: IO ()
main  =  do  
    let list = Node 3 (Node 2 (NodeWithoutNext 7))
    print (list)
    print (list >>= (\x -> NodeWithoutNext (x+200)))
```

I get error-

```
Bla.hs:16:39: error:
    * Couldn't match type `b' with `LinkedList b'
      `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          (>>=) :: forall a b.
                   LinkedList a -> (a -> LinkedList b) -> Linked
        at Bla.hs:15:24-26
      Expected type: LinkedList (LinkedList b)
        Actual type: LinkedList b
    * In the second argument of `Node', namely `(next >>= f)'
      In the expression: Node (f a) (next >>= f)
      In an equation for `>>=':
          (Node a next) >>= f = Node (f a) (next >>= f)
    * Relevant bindings include
        f :: a -> LinkedList b (bound at Bla.hs:16:22)
        (>>=) :: LinkedList a -> (a -> LinkedList b) -> LinkedLi
          (bound at Bla.hs:15:24)
   |
16 |    (Node a next) >>= f =  Node (f a) (next >>= f)
   |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

What do I need to fix here?
The problem is on the line that is with **.

Comment: You forgot to close a bracket on the last line of the `Monad` instance.

Comment: But that being said, usually the bind of a list a `concatMap`, since `f` takes as input an `a`, and outputs an `m a`.

Comment: I added now the bracket but this is the error.

Comment: I don't understand, what do I need to do with the concatMap?

Comment: Before implementing a function, it is useful to (a) look to the documentation to see which contracts bind should satisfy, (b) the signature to know what the function is supposed to do.

Comment: Hi, you really right but I looked on both of the things you told me and still don't know how to fit my data type LinkedList to the monad..

Comment: Look carefully: your definition of `>>=` isn't really any different than `fmap`; it just reverses the order of the arguments. For a monad to be worth the fuss, it should do *something* (and indeed it does) that an ordinary functor cannot do.

Comment: Your applicative instance does not handle all cases. It is usually convenient to define the monad instance first, and then let `pure=return ; (<*>)=ap` hence defining the applicative instance exploiting the more general monad instance.

Comment: Also, to multiply each element of your list by a given number, you don't *need* a monad; that's exactly what the `Functor` instance does (and must do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type system will complain, since the "bind" operator `>>=` has signature:

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

So let us specialize the signature for the `LinkedList`:

```
(>>=) :: LinkedList a -> (a -> LinkedList b) -> LinkedList b
```

So the function takes at the left side a `LinkedList a`, and at the right side a function that maps an `a` (!) to a `LinkedList b`, and we expect the outcome to be a `LinkedList b`. The function you have defined can not do that: since if you construct a `Node (f a) (next >>= f)`, the result will be a `LinkedList (LinkedList b)`. Indeed, you apply `f` to `a` (the head of the list), which yields a `LinkedList b` (as head of the `Node`).

If we look at the signature above, there are perhaps some ideas that might come up, but the most straightforward idea, is probably to implement some sort of `concatMap :: [a] -> (a -> [b]) -> [b]`. The "bind" has to satisfy the following rules:

1. `return a >>= k  =  k a`;
2. `m >>= return  =  m`; and
3. `m >>= (\x -> k x >>= h)  =  (m >>= k) >>= h`.

the `concatMap` function satisfies the three constraints. (1) If we wrap a value `x` into a `LinkedList`, and apply `f` on every element (of the singleton list), we will obtain a list that contains one list, that of the result of `k a`, but by using the `concat` of `concatMap`, we flatten this again. (2) If we would use `m >>= return` with concat, we will wrap every element in a new singleton list, but the concatenation, will unwrap it again.

So we can implement it as:

```
instance Monad LinkedList where
   return = NodeWithoutNext
   (NodeWithoutNext a) >>= f = f a
   (Node a next) >>= f =  build (f a)
       where build (NodeWithoutNext x) = (Node x (next >>= f))
             build (Node x xs) = Node x (build xs)
```

So here `build` will iterate through the `LinkedList` produced by `f a`, and basically construct an *almost* duplicate, except that when we reach the end, we will continue with the concatenation of the outcome of the bind of the remaining elements.